# Converting integer to time format in excel

Tags: excel

```
Date
19112018
19112016
19112015
19112013
```

I have a column named Date.

I want to convert 19112018 to 2019-11-20 18:00

19 means year 2019

11 month

20 days

18 is hour

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula:

```
=DATE(20&LEFT(A2,2),MID(A2,3,2),MID(A2,5,2))+RIGHT(A2,2)/24
```

Or:

```
=--(20&REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A2,7,0," "),5,0,"-"),3,0,"-")&":00")
```

Then format the output cell:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm
```

[image]